# How to batch change exif data for JPEG photo files (wrong date set in camera)?

Tags: exif

I have taken 300 photos at an event.  Afterwards I noticed that the date was set incorrectly in the camera - one day off.  There are lots of EXIF data in the files, not just creation dates.

How can I change only the dates contained within all relevant EXIF fields to correct the date (minus one day exactly)?

No other data should be changed by this modification!

Perhaps for each file I could dump the data (`exiftool` or `exiv2`?), then modify the dump (with `awk`?), then replace EXIF data from the modified dump?  But how?

EDIT:

There is a lot of data per file:

```
# exiftool IMG_9040.JPG | wc 
    289    2218   13996
```

Lots of it are dates:

```
# exiftool IMG_9040.JPG | grep 2021 | grep -v File
Modify Date                     : 2021:11:02 17:06:58
Date/Time Original              : 2021:11:02 17:06:58
Create Date                     : 2021:11:02 17:06:58
Create Date                     : 2021:11:02 17:06:58.24+01:00
Date/Time Original              : 2021:11:02 17:06:58.24+01:00
Modify Date                     : 2021:11:02 17:06:58.24+01:00
```

I wish to change all of these.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one photo's EXIF data?

Comment: @jubilatious1 That's about 300 lines. Added the relevant parts!

Comment: Answer below, but also check out: https://exiftool.org/forum/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exiftool has an `-alldates` parameter:

```
exiftool -alldates-=24 -filemodifydate-=24 -filecreatedate-=24   *.jpg
```

The above code works to subtract 24 hours according to this Forum comment (by Phil Harvey):

https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6330.msg31354#msg31354

You can combine the above code with an `-out` file specification, like `-out ./newJPG.jpg` or (in a new directory), with `-out ./newdir/newJPG.jpg`. The `-out` specification gets inserted directly after the call to `exiftool`.

You can also try adding to the `-out` file specification ( **after making backups!** ), the option`-overwrite_original` OR  `-overwrite_original_in_place`, inserted directly after the call to `exiftool`. See `exiftool --help` for details.

Note, an earlier revision of this post suggested using the  `-globalTimeShift` parameter, as in:

```
exiftool -globalTimeShift -24 -time:all  *.jpg
```

However (according to Phil Harvey), *"The `-globalTimeShift` option is needed only when you want to copy a shifted date/time value to another tag."*, such as a `-geo` tag. See:

https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=9224.msg47655#msg47655
https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6330.msg31354#msg31354

https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html
https://exiftool.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can type :

```
exiftool -EXIF:CreateDate+=24 img.jpg
```

To add 24 hour.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the data from an example file above. Do I need to do that for each of these dates separately? (How?)

Comment: You can add extra parameters to adjust each one. The documentation for exiftool is pretty good